# JSON schema definition for the GitHub API

Tags: swagger, github-api, jsonschema

Is there a JSON schema, or swagger definition of the github api? Is there a good resource like that defining other widely used apis?

I have looked at the github docs, and don't see any mention of a code definition of the api. If there is no official version, perhaps there is an unofficial one somewhere..?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Billy, take a look at [APIs Guru](https://apis.guru/browse-apis/)'s catalog and filter by `Github`.

That should be a good starting point.

Comment: Btw, github also released **Graph QL** which has greater flexibility. See https://developer.github.com/v4/

Answer (score 0):

For RAML you have [this](https://www.mulesoft.com/exchange#!/?types=RAML).
It has the GitHub API